# UIAlertController is not is window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

Im trying to show up a pop up containing a `UIPickerView` and `UITextField`.

Following is my code that I use to create the pop up.

```
self.alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, 200);
    UIPickerView *regionsPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    regionsPicker.tag = 1;
    regionsPicker.dataSource = (id <UIPickerViewDataSource>)self;
    regionsPicker.delegate = (id <UIPickerViewDelegate>) self;
    [regionsPicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

    UIView *toolView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270.0f, 44.f)];
    toolView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 100, 30);
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, button.titleLabel.frame.size.width, 0, -button.titleLabel.frame.size.width);
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"];
    [button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor: [UIColor blueColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [toolView addSubview:button];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(closeDialog:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    self.textField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 170, 220, 200)];
    _textField.editable = NO;
    _textField.hidden=true;
    self.textField.text = @"Enter text...";
    self.textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    self.textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    self.textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    self.textField.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.textField.delegate = (id <UITextViewDelegate>) self;
    self.textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    self.textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

    [toolView addSubview:self.textField];

    CGRect actionFrame = CGRectMake(80, 400, 100, 30);
    UIButton *actionBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: actionFrame];
    [actionBtn setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [actionBtn setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [actionBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    [self.textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [toolView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.alert.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.alert.view addSubview:regionsPicker];
    [self.alert.view addSubview:self.textField];
    [self.alert.view addSubview:toolView];
    [self.alert.view addSubview:actionBtn];
    id rootViewController=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
    if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        rootViewController=[((UINavigationController *)rootViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [rootViewController presentViewController:_alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It works fine.However, if Im trying to enter text in the `UITextField` by tapping it, the keyboard doesn't appear and hence Im not be able to type anything within the `UITextField`. How can I sort this out?

Comment: Question: why your `textField` height is `200` when font size is just `15.0f`? Also Show code where to you implemented `UITextFieldDelegate` methods.

Comment: I don't think you should add subview to a `UIAlertController` but rather use a custom made version of "UIAlertController" instead.

Comment: is it possible by any means that I can show a view or view controller as a pop up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the reason is you added `textField`, `button`, all those inside toolview , but the `toolview` height is very less

change your toolView height from  44
into 500 or else (combination of textfield, button + 50).
Change below statement

```
UIView *toolView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270.0f, 44.f)];
```

to

```
 UIView *toolView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270.0f, 500.f)];
```

**Update**

change this line

```
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

into

```
   id rootViewController=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
{
  rootViewController=[((UINavigationController *)rootViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
}
[rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Update New**

```
  UIViewController *rootViewController=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
{
  rootViewController=[((UINavigationController *)rootViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
}else
{
   while (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
    rootViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
}
 }
[rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Swift**

```
 var rootViewController: UIViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window.rootViewController
if (rootViewController is UINavigationController.self) {
rootViewController = ((rootViewController as! UINavigationController)).viewControllers[0]
}
else {
while rootViewController.presentedViewController {
    rootViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController
}
}
rootViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

Comment: negative voters can explain the reason  for downvote

Comment: whats the problem , if you need the clarification Surely I will explain,

Comment: it is solved partially... when its in landscape mode, the UIAlertController is not is window hierarchy

Comment: @user22312412 - simple bro,ok where you decalred your code

Comment: it'll be better if i can show a view or view controller as a pop up but I dont find a possible way through which I can achieve it

Comment: dont think like , you are near in closer, if you modify something its works better,

Comment: I have declared it within IBAction

Comment: Im getting the following error message bro...Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x15e6b0310> on <ViewController: 0x15e640620> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: surely works , the reason we find the top most viewcontroller,

Comment: may i know what is presentedViewController?

Comment: its showing error in presentedViewController and rootViewController as property not found

Comment: @KaruppuMGR - sorry bro , chnage this `while (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        rootViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;` and try once

Comment: What changes i have to make to while loop bro?

Comment: change this line `topController.presentedViewController`  into `rootViewController.presentedViewController`

Comment: it worked perfectly bro...but in landscape mode, the view is not fully visible

Comment: @KaruppuMGR - happy to hear bro, then check and set your frames (x, y, width, and height ) based on device widths , anyway if my answer is useful please accept it is useful in future

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you:-

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@" Your message " preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIView *toolView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, 200)];
toolView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 100, 30);
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
[button setTitle:@"Image" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[toolView addSubview:button];

UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, 44)];
txtField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txtField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
txtField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
txtField.placeholder = @"enter text";
txtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
txtField.delegate = (id<UITextFieldDelegate>)self;

[toolView addSubview:txtField];

[txtField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[toolView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[alertController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[alertController.view addSubview:toolView];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```